# Scrapy - crawled (200) and referer : none

Tags: python, scrapy, referer

I'm trying to learn how to use scrapy and python but I'm not an expert at all... very far from here.
I always have an empty file after crawling this page : [product of c-discount](http://www.cdiscount.com/mpv-8732-SATENCO.html) and I don't understand why...

Here is my code :

```
import scrapy

from cdiscount_test.items import CdiscountTestItem

f = open('items.csv', 'w').close()

class CdiscountsellersspiderSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'CDiscountSellersSpider'
    allowed_domains = ['cdiscount.com']
    start_urls = ['http://www.cdiscount.com/mpv-8732-SATENCO.html']

    def parse(self, response):
        items = CdiscountTestItem()
        name = response.xpath('//div[@class="shtName"]/div[@class="shtOver"]/h1[@itemprop="name"]/text()').extract()
        country = response.xpath('//div[@class="shtName"]/span[@class="shTopCExp"]/text()').extract()

        items['name_seller'] = ''.join(name).strip()
        items['country_seller'] = ''.join(country).strip()
        pass
```

And the result I get in the cmd windows :

```
2017-06-20 18:01:50 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2017-06-20 18:01:50 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 
pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2017-06-20 18:01:50 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] DEBUG: Telnet console 
listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2017-06-20 18:01:51 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET 
http://www.cdiscount.com/robots.txt> (referer: None)
2017-06-20 18:01:51 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET 
http://www.cdiscount.com/mpv-8732-SATENCO.html> (referer: None)
2017-06-20 18:01:51 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
```

Is there someone to help me please?

Thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem here is that you don't pass the item from the `parse` method back to Scrapy engine. Your last command in `parse` is `pass`, so you just discard the item. Instead, you need to pass the item from spider to Scrapy engine for further processing using `yield item`.

Comment: Ok, my bad... Thank you!! I was searching something complicated where just a yield was usefull...

Comment: And do you know '.re()' ? I saw something like that to keep just a part of en extract text but I don't know which are the args to put into the ()

Answer (score 3):

One probable scenario for the same issue might be the website content is producing dynamically. You can check that by going to the website and tapping view page source.
In such cases, you might have to use splash along with scrapy.